# Rsync not transferring the changes

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to sync this local file (release.txt) to a server (verlis) in which I have ssh into, into the same path directory in which it also contains the same file.

And so, I did the following:

- ssh verlis
- rsync -av /tools/packageA/release.txt verlis:/tools/packageA/release.txt

The process was very fast and so when I tried doing a `cat release.txt` to view and make sure that the change I did has been mapped onto the verlis server but it did not.

I tried to use sudo, or change it to compare using diorectory, same thing - release.txt file is not having the change I have made. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from your local machine:

```
rsync -ave "ssh" /tools/packageA/release.txt user@server.com:/tools/packageA/release.txt
```